# display:inline behaves differently when used inside a <td>

Tags: html, css

Iam trying to add html piece of code to an existing html page. I am trying to use a DIV inside TD, then display:inline css attribute for DIV, doesn't work as expected. Any reason why ?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="20%" class="oddrow"></td>
        <td  width="80%" class="oddrow-l">
            <div style="display: inline;"> Hello</div>
            <div style="display: inline;"> 
                Hiii
            </div>
        </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the expected and actual output?

Comment: How do you expect it to work? and what do you mean by "_doesn't work_"? please explain.

Comment: Because the table has no width, the 80% results to 0pixel. Because you have no `white-space:nowrap` the lines appear from top to bottom, not from left to right.

Comment: @PeterRader is correct. If you remove the widths on the columns the divs render side by side: http://jsfiddle.net/59RY9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add your display:inline to the td style as well. http://jsfiddle.net/v5Ld3/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="20%" class="oddrow"></td>
        <td  width="80%" class="oddrow-l" style"display: inline">
            <div style"display: inline">Hello</div>
            <div style"display: inline">Hiii</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Setting the `<td>` to `display: inline;` will of course prevent it from displaying like a table cell... i doubt this is what OP really wants.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set width for your table:

```
table {
   width: 100%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LKizB

Answer (score 0):

Use `<span>` instead of `<div>`.   Also as others mentioned your table nor td have width defined, so they will use as small width as possible.  `span` is inline anyway and could change that.

If you don't want the whole table being `width: 100%` you may just set width for the problematic column.

Comment: The code from the question `<div style="display: inline;">` will render the same as a `<span>`

Comment: YEs, but `<span>` is quite proper there as you dont need to use any additional styles for it - its inline element already.. http://jsfiddle.net/4XhCE/ (Added border=1 just to fast force borders visibility -  dont use that in working code--_--)

Comment: But you are avoiding the issue of the question entirely, it's not the span but the border in your demo making it render differently (for some reason). http://jsfiddle.net/4XhCE/1/

Comment: In HTML5 it is allowed to use block-level-elements inside inline elements. If the TS is using HTML5 this code is okay. Personally I would rather use a `span` too. (end.of.offtopic)

Comment: I have added the border after it worked, not before.

Comment: @Seti did you see the demo I posted? Chrome renders the items beneath eachother.